# How do I run this SQL query in VB.NET?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I have this query working successfully, Now my requirement is to execute this code in VB.NET (Visual Studio 2010). It is an `UPDATE` command. How do I convert and run this in VB.NET?

```
DECLARE @Rt int
SET @Rt = 0

UPDATE DB.dbo.Sales
SET @Rt = Total = @Rt + Area1 + Area2
FROM DB.dbo.Sales
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
Dim query as string = "UPDATE DB.dbo.Sales SET @Rt = Total = @Rt + Area1 + Area2 FROM Sales"
Dim updateCommand as new SqlCommand(query, SqlConnection)
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rt",0)
If 0 <> updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() Then 'Number of rows affected by the query
'Update command was successfull.
End If
```

Comment: Mr. Anuraj I proved about you the code is very very useful to me. Since long time I was stuck with this code. Thanks a lot.