# Convert SQL Query to vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

Can help me to run the SQL Query in VB.NET .This is the query for converting table data in to csv

```
USE newdb 
 GO
 -- Check Table Column
 SELECT *
 FROM accountexample 
 GO
 -- Get CSV values
 SELECT SUBSTRING(
 (SELECT ' ' + s.BPl + ',' + s.Lo  + ',' + s.Ltion + ',' + s.Ite + ',' + s.HNO + ',' + s.QNo + ',' + s.Country + ',' + s.STATE + ',' + s.Rem + CHAR(10)
  FROM   accountexample s
 ORDER BY s.BPl
 FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) AS CSV
 GO
```

Comment: You don't convert SQL to VB.NET. You can run a SQL query with VB.NET. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610536/how-do-i-run-this-sql-query-in-vb-net

Comment: showing error -
    Dim QUERY As String = "SELECT * from DB.dbo.accountexample 
 ("SELECT ' ' + s.BPl + ',' + s.Lo + ',' + s.Ltion + ',' + s.Ite + ',' + s.HNO + ',' + s.QNo + ',' + s.Country + ',' + s.STATE + ',' + s.Rem + CHAR(10) FROM DB.dbo.accountexample s ORDER BY s.BPl FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) AS CSV")

Comment: @SudrSh: Are you want to convert the select query results into CSV file?

Comment: @SudrSh, What error did you get ?

Answer (score 0):

First select required records into dataset

And then use the following function to convert dataset into CSV file.

Function to convert dataset to CSV

```
Sub SetDataTable_To_CSV(ByVal dtable As DataTable, ByVal path_filename As String, ByVal sep_char As String)

    Dim writer As System.IO.StreamWriter

    Try

        writer = New System.IO.StreamWriter(path_filename)



        Dim _sep As String = ""

        Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder

        For Each col As DataColumn In dtable.Columns

            builder.Append(_sep).Append(col.ColumnName)

            _sep = sep_char

        Next

        writer.WriteLine(builder.ToString())



        For Each row As DataRow In dtable.Rows

            _sep = ""

            builder = New System.Text.StringBuilder



            For Each col As DataColumn In dtable.Columns

                builder.Append(_sep).Append(row(col.ColumnName))

                _sep = sep_char

            Next

            writer.WriteLine(builder.ToString())

        Next

    Catch ex As Exception



    Finally

        If Not writer Is Nothing Then writer.Close()

    End Try

End Sub
```

Taken from following links

http://redsouljaz.com/2010/06/03/vb-net-set-data-table-to-csv-file/

If you want to do with my sql side thru VB.net.

Then you can create stored procedure

```
CREATE PROC ConvertCSV
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT SUBSTRING(
 (SELECT ' ' + s.BPl + ',' + s.Lo  + ',' + s.Ltion + ',' + s.Ite + ',' + s.HNO + ',' + s.QNo + ',' + s.Country + ',' + s.STATE + ',' + s.Rem + CHAR(10)
  FROM   accountexample s
 ORDER BY s.BPl
 FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) AS CSV
END
```

And then call this procedure from the from vb.net

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=<datasource>;Initial Catalog=<databasename>;User ID=<username>;Password=<password>")
con.Open()

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("ConvertCSV", con)

Try
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Finally
    If cmd IsNot Nothing Then cmd.Dispose()
    If cn IsNot Nothing AndAlso cn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then cn.Close()
End Try
```

Hope this helps